# error 500 for .htaccess error

Tags: linux, lamp, .htaccess

I am running a LAMP server, and this .htaccess is giving me a 500 error.  What this does is filter keywords and redirect to the respective domain names.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xy|yz|xz
RewriteRule ^xyz.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ab|bc|ac
RewriteRule ^abc.net


<IfModule>
```

Why does it give me a 500 error, do I have to check if IfModule is installed, or has to be installed.

Comment: show / check Apache error log

Comment: @jet the error.log

/var/www/conf/.htaccess: <IfModule> directive requires additional arguments, referer: http://localhost/conf/rewrite.php

Comment: Shouldn't you have a closing / on the <IfModule>?

Comment: @emgee did that, still have the issue

Answer (score 1):

You didn't properly close the IfModule container. You need to use </IfModule> at the end. You simply forgot the /

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- The mod_rewrite module is installed. `a2enmod rewrite`
- If your httpd.conf/apache.conf has `AllowOverride None` set, you'll get an error. I think it's a different error though.
- You may need to set a RewriteBase directive.
- Make sure you reload the configuration file as needed — `apache2ctl restart`